# Is copyToSection supported for consumer notebooks

Tags: onenote-api

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-copy), it looks like CopyToSection may not be supported for consumer notebooks, but it looks like some other copy APIs are.  To be sure, I decided to try it.

When I do a call like:

```
POST /api/v1.0/me/notes/pages/0-3ab2f203744607310cfc151d657bf461!1-922579950926BF9E!1760/copyToSection HTTP/1.1
```

I get a 501 like:

```
"error":{
    "code":"20111",
    "message":"OData Feature not implemented.    
    "@api.url":"http://aka.ms/onenote-errors#C20111"
  }
```

Before I try harder to see if it works, anyone from MS able to say if copyToSection is or is not supported on consumer notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

I am from the Onenote team. Copy Api's are only supported for Office 365.

Comment: Thanks Amol!   Is there an ETA for when Copy APIs will come to consumer? The copy apis are super useful as I need full fidelity copies of my pages. If I try to use GET/POST to clone pages I lose some page formatting.